# Fiĝioj vs Fiĝio: When should island groups have the plural ending?

Tags: plurals

This has been a mystery to me for some time. When should the Esperanto name of an island group receive the plural ending *-j*?

- *Sejŝeloj, Filipinoj, Ferooj, Ŝetlandoj, Orkadoj, Falklandoj* are usually plural
- *Fiĝio* is [sometimes](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/Fi%C4%9Dio) in the singular, [sometimes](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fi%C4%9Dioj) in the plural, *Fiĝioj*
- Lots of island groups are always in the singular: *Mikronezio, Tuvalo, Malto* (cf. the English expression *the Maltese Islands*)

I guess that some of these names are shortened from the expression ”-*aj insuloj*”, like *Feroaj Insuloj* > *Ferooj*. But the same expression could be used with any of the above names, e.g. *Mikroneziaj Insuloj*. And while we’re at it, why not *Japanioj* for Japan, another island group? The whole system seems very chaotic to me; hope somebody can help. :-)

Comment: Sub-question: Is there any reason that we say *Feroaj Insuloj* (> *Ferooj*) rather than *Feroa Insularo*, which would result in *Feroo* (and add consistency to the names)?

Comment: **(1)** Mind: not only islands: the Netherlands (fortunately became Nederlando, as the Duth themselves names it). **(2)** Mikronezio is a group word like _-uj'_ **(3)** Country names are very naturalistic, near to the native description = chaotic.

Answer (score 6):

It depends what the term actually refers to, a political or a geographical entity.

*Japanujo* refers to the country, not the physical islands; hence it is in the singular. The same would apply to *Malto* and the other examples. Same as in English, where you talk about *Malta* as the political entity, and the *Maltese Islands* when you're referring to the actual pieces of rock in the water.

The Orkneys, Falkland Islands/Islas Malvinas etc are not a political entity, but a group of multiple islands, hence you're using the plural.

Comment: But Filipinoj, Sejŝeloj, Maldivoj and Fiĝioj are also political entities?

Comment: Good point. The Philippines and Maldives are also plural in other languages, so I would think they are exceptions, and _Fiĝio_ would be the country, while _Fiĝioj_ is the islands. The full title of the country is _Respubliko Insuloj Fiĝio_. Unfortunately nothing in language is ever black and white.

Comment: Yes, many of the names are probably just carried over from other languages, whether it makes sense or not… :-/ (For example, I don’t see the reason that *Maldivoj* should be plural and *Indonezio* not.) *Fiĝio(j)* is a really confusing example. Does it mean that one could make a similar distinction when talking about other countries either in the sense of states or island groups? Like: *Malto* (state) – *Maltoj* (island group), or *Tuvalo* (state) – *Tuvaloj* (island group). And what if *Falklandoj/Malvinoj* became independent, should the state be called *Falklando/Malvino*?

Comment: Mind that -nez- comes from the greek for islands, so it's like x island nation. It does make sense that this is always singular.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule. It tends to follow the form of the name of the country by which it is known internationally. In the case of Fiji, I have no idea which language influenced the use of the plural. Indeed, checking two dictionaries, one has only Fiĝioj (PIV), and the other only Fiĝio (ReVo). In any case, there's no logic to this, some things just have singular or plural names, just like in English.

La Akademio de Esperanto recommends Fiĝio.

Comment: Exactly. By international law a state chooses its own name. In this case Matanitu ko Viti, Republic of Fiji or फ़िजी गणराज्य (in the official languages in the order given in Wikipedia). In the name of reciprocity other states try to follow this proper name, so in Esperanto the official name is **Respubliko Fiĝio**, inofficially **Fiĝio**. I have no idea where the plural name comes from, it certainly is not the name of the state.